# "Key" prop in map

Tags: javascript, reactjs, map-function

Newbie here, Sorry for the silly question :)

How am gonna put the "Key" prop in this function?

The code is on the above of ContactShadows. I tried many ways but all the methods I tried are not working properly. Can you please check and tell me how am gonna put the "Key" props?

```
    import React, { Suspense, useEffect, useMemo, useRef, useState } from "react";

import "./PartOne.css";

const PartOne = () => {
const [rooms, setRooms] = useState([
    Room1,
    Room2,
    Room3,
    Room4,
    Room5,
    Room6,
    Room7,
    Room8
]);

useEffect(() => {
    console.log("rooms state:", rooms);
}, [rooms]);

return (
    <div className="wrapper">
        {rooms.map((room, roomIndex) =>
            room({ position: positions[roomIndex] })
        )}
    </div>
);
};
export default PartOne;
```

Thank You

Comment: Where are `Room1` `Room2` etc come from?

Comment: And why are they called like functions?

Comment: Maybe you can wrap the room function in a div and put the key prop on the div?

Comment: Actually they are 3D objects

Comment: @Anvay I tried to do that. But not working

Comment: Not enough code added to help you completely. However you should understand why key properties are used and how you can go about them. But to help you solve this issue, you can just wrap the function in a span or fragmant.

{rooms.map((room, roomIndex) =>
            <span key={randomKey}>{room({ position: positions[roomIndex] })</span>}
        )}

Comment: Is it still throwing an error?

Comment: Here's the full code:
https://codesandbox.io/s/4-thhhhhhhhhhhhh-zpi03t?file=/src/components/PartOne.js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could wrap that element from `room` function in a `<React.Fragment>` and assign the `key` on it:

```js
return (
    <div className="wrapper">
        {rooms.map((room, roomIndex) => (
            <React.Fragment key={`${roomIndex}`}>
                {room({ position: positions[roomIndex] })}
            </React.Fragment>
        ))}
    </div>
);
```